# I'm trying to decode this file that supposed to encode an imaged obtained by a laser system

Tags: file-format

This file suppose to have an image obtained from a Laser system. Since it needs a propietary software for the decoder I have been slowed in order to get the data. I wonder if you guys know any way of decoding the information that is in this file. I tried using the fuzzy logic toolbox from matlab that says that reads a .fis file, but could not get it to work. Any ideas very welcome. [Sample file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18j0LWbhWO2VX8RAlbJ-QkGwvJw22LXCi/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a simple glance ofthefile with a hexeditor says there are two jpegs inside the file
just carve the data between the signature ffd8ffe0 -----ffd9 and look if that is what you are interested in?

```
:\>e:\GIT\usr\bin\xxd.exe "1IC4A 0.045 (1).fis" | grep -B 4 -A 4 JFIF


000ffdb0: c154 3335 ad75 75c0 58db 4556 4e23 1dd3  .T35.uu.X.EVN#..
000ffdc0: c685 da86 b636 bc05 1bc2 be06 5202 c358  .....6......R..X
000ffdd0: a181 00c5 503d 170c 16c8 80da 2d43 5a84  ....P=......-CZ.
000ffde0: 754a 5606 551a 7946 8c1a d194 0100 0000  uJV.U.yF........
000ffdf0: cca1 0700 ffd8 ffe0 0010 4a46 4946 0001  ..........JFIF..
000ffe00: 0200 0001 0001 0000 fffe 0037 4a50 4547  ...........7JPEG
000ffe10: 2065 6e63 6f64 6572 2062 6173 6564 206f   encoder based o
000ffe20: 6e20 6970 704a 5020 5b37 2e30 2e31 3034  n ippJP [7.0.104
000ffe30: 315d 202d 204a 756c 2031 3920 3230 3131  1] - Jul 19 2011
--
002748e0: 50e2 b6ea 147e 51f7 61fe c1c3 1f89 a48b  P....~Q.a.......
002748f0: 8fa0 832d daf3 ca7a 0362 bfd2 7f24 8e74  ...-...z.b...$.t
00274900: 1300 cd7a 10c2 e192 e208 0e14 5269 14c0  ...z........Ri..
00274910: 3332 251c 9972 f805 e06c 0100 0000 4a07  32%..r...l....J.
00274920: 0700 ffd8 ffe0 0010 4a46 4946 0001 0200  ........JFIF....
00274930: 0001 0001 0000 fffe 0037 4a50 4547 2065  .........7JPEG e
00274940: 6e63 6f64 6572 2062 6173 6564 206f 6e20  ncoder based on
00274950: 6970 704a 5020 5b37 2e30 2e31 3034 315d  ippJP [7.0.1041]
00274960: 202d 204a 756c 2031 3920 3230 3131 00ff   - Jul 19 2011..
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Sorry for my ignorance, I am unsure how to extract the image. Should I make two new files starting from the signature with the jpeg extension?

Comment: Found a way: https://github.com/ReFirmLabs/binwalk/wiki/Usage.  You just need to use binwalk -D and it will extract the files. Thanks a lot @blabb!